# Vue.js: @input for <input> not working with v-for

Tags: vue.js, html-input, v-for

I am creating my own custom `<input>` `Vue` component. What I am doing is that the user can never enter the wrong type of input. For that I am using `regex.test()` at each input.

This is my code for my `Vue` component for taking an integer element or an integer array:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <label>{{ label }}
            <template v-if="isArray">
                <input 
                    v-model="arr[i - 1]" 
                    @input="filterInput" 
                    :disabled="disableWhen" 
                    v-for="i in arraySize" 
                    :key="i">
                </input>
            </template>
            <template v-else>
                <input 
                    v-model="num" 
                    @input="filterInput" 
                    :disabled="disableWhen">
                </input>
            </template>
        </label>
        <el-button 
            type="success" 
            icon="el-icon-check" 
            circle 
            @click="confirm" 
            :disabled="disableWhen">
        </el-button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            label: String,
            nonNegative: Boolean,
            disableWhen: Boolean,
            isArray: Boolean,
            arraySize: Number
        },
        data() {
            return {
                num: '',
                arr: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            filterInput() {
                if (this.nonNegative) {
                    if (!/^[0-9]*$/.test(this.num)) {
                        this.num = '';
                    }
                } else if (!/^(-)?[0-9]*$/.test(this.num)) {
                    this.num = '';
                }
            },
            confirm() {
                if (this.isArray) {
                    let validArrayInput = true;
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.arraySize; i++) {
                        if (!this.validInput(this.arr[i])) {
                            validArrayInput = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (validArrayInput) {
                        this.$emit('confirm', this.arr);
                    }
                } else if (this.validInput(this.num)) {
                    this.$emit('confirm', this.num);
                }
            },
            validInput(x) {
                return (x !== '' && x !== '-' && typeof x !== "undefined");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The code is working correctly when `isArray = false`, that is, for integer elements. But the method `filterInput` is never being called when `isArray = true`, and there is no restriction for the wrong input. What is the problem?

Comment: `arr` is set to an empty array and nowhere in the posted code is this changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filterInput` is being called fine for both types of input but it only attempts to manipulate `num`, it doesn't change `arr`.

Here's my attempt at implementing this:

```js
const MyInput = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <label>{{ label }}
        <template v-if="isArray">
          <input 
            v-for="i in arraySize" 
            v-model="arr[i - 1]" 
            :disabled="disableWhen" 
            :key="i"
            @input="filterInput" 
          >
        </template>
        <template v-else>
          <input 
            v-model="num" 
            :disabled="disableWhen"
            @input="filterInput"
          >
        </template>
      </label>
    </div>  
  `,

  props: {
    label: String,
    nonNegative: Boolean,
    disableWhen: Boolean,
    isArray: Boolean,
    arraySize: Number
  },
  
  data() {
    return {
      arr: []
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    num: {
      get () {
        return this.arr[0]
      },
      
      set (num) {
        this.arr[0] = num
      }
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    filterInput() {
      const arr = this.arr
      const re = this.nonNegative ? /^\d*$/ : /^-?\d*$/
      
      for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; ++index) {
        if (!re.test(arr[index])) {
          this.$set(arr, index, '')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    MyInput
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-input label="Single"></my-input>
  <br>
  <my-input label="Multiple" is-array :array-size="3"></my-input>
</div>
```

A few notes:

1. I've changed `num` to be a computed property backed by `arr[0]`. This simplifies the filtering logic as it only has to consider `arr` for both types of input. It could be simplified further, e.g. the template doesn't really need to handle two cases, it could treat single-valued just the same as multi-valued but with `array-size` of 1. Only the value that's emitted (not included in my code) really needs to have different behaviour for the single-valued case. With a little refactoring `num` could probably be removed altogether.
2. The implementation is painfully stateful. You're going to run into difficulties if you ever want to pass in values from the outside.
3. Rather than setting the values to `''` I would suggest just stripping out the disallowed characters using `replace`. I have not made this change in my code, I wanted to retain the behaviour from the original example.
4. Closing `</input>` tags are invalid and I have removed them.
5. There was a lot of duplication in your `filterInput` method that I've tried to remove. It now checks all the entries in the `arr` array. There didn't seem to be any need to target the specific input that had changed.
6. `this.$set` is used as it's updating an array by index, which otherwise would not be detected by the reactivity system (the standard caveat for manipulating arrays).